# How to create and use common mixin in Laravel 8/Inertia.js/vuejs3 application?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

in vuejs2 applications I created common mixin and referenced it in resources/js/app.js like :

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';

import common from "./common";
Vue.mixin(common);
```

But I failed to make similar in  Laravel 8/Inertia.js 0.4/vuejs3 application :

```
import Vue from 'vue' // i got compile error : export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
// Vue = required('vue')  // GOT RUN TIME ERROR : app.js:26221 Uncaught ReferenceError: required is not defined

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';


import common from "./appMixin";
Vue.mixin(common);
```

How can I do it ?
Also I used global Vue in many parts of application, like reading process env variables.

How can I do it in Inertia.js /vuejs app ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 3 you should first create the app and then apply the mixin:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  // root instance stuff here
})

app.mixin({
  // ...mixin stuff here
})

app.mount('#app')
```